# Multi Domain Cookies Consent —Special Category Data

Tags: gdpr, privacy, cookies

Can cross domain cookie consent be applied to government websites which collect special category data?

Or is there any legal\policy guidance covering the use of multi domain cookies consent for the EU? The privacy directive does not appear to have much specific content on this.

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: The law doesn't care about domain names. Instead, the question would be whether consent would still be sufficiently free and informed. However, you'll notice that browsers have increasingly limited support for third-party cookies and may apply first-party isolation / state partitioning so that domain A wouldn't be able to communicate consent status to domain B via a shared cookie.